# Python 3.8 Getting IndexError: list index out of range when array seems to be sh

Tags: python, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am accessing indexes within the total number of indexes, print("TOTAL ARRAY INDEXES = " + str(len(row))).  For example, if I attempt to access a data element **19** within the array named **row****[19]** that has **21 indexes** from str(len(row)), I get the error below.  But this doesn't seem to make sense because the total number of indexes is 21.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-24440423f6ad> in <module>
    135 
    136 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 137     main()

<ipython-input-68-24440423f6ad> in main()
    113 
    114 
--> 115             g_deliv_date = row[19]
    116 
    117
```

This is my array and size named "value":

```
TOTAL ARRAY INDEXES = 21
['', 'College-EMV', '617', '328', 'CCC-1489', 'COLLEGE', 'College', 'EMV', 'In Progress', 'Upgrade', '10nnn', 'ID:  nn/KG/569 /PT\nOrder Number:    N7 / CLO 001\nCompletion Date:  10/6/2020\n', 'Telco', 'Tunde', '10/6/2020', '10/6/20- information received.\n3/12/20- ordered', '', '', '3/12/2020', '9/24/2020', '10/6/2020']
G_CCC_KEY_ID [4]= CCC-1489
g_sitea_to_sitez[1] = College-EMV
g_imp_jira = 617
g_order_jira[2] = 328
g_cir_sz[10] = 10nnn
g_ccd[5] = COLLEGE 
g_telco[12] = Telco
g_cirid[11] = ID:  nn/KG/569 /PT\nOrder Number:    N7 / CLO 001\nCompletion Date:  10/6/2020\n
g_last_contacted[14] = 10/6/2020
g_status[15] = 10/6/20- information received.
3/12/20- ordered
g_internal[16] = 
g_start_date[17] = 
g_order_date[18] = 3/12/2020
g_deliv_date[19] = 
g_cpe_date[22] = 
g_ops_ready[24] =
```

PYTHON SCRIPT: The script is below and its purpose is to download a GoogleSheet and assign the row/columns to variables in the script.  The Google Sheet has columns is **A-Z**.

```
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'In Progress 10Gbps!A2:Z'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        for row in values:
            # 
                        
            print("TOTAL ARRAY INDEXES = " + str(len(row)))
            print(row)
            
            g_ccc_key_id = row[4]
            print("G_CCC_KEY_ID [4]= " + g_ccc_key_id)
            
            g_sitea_to_sitez = row[1]
            print("g_sitea_to_sitez[1] = " + g_sitea_to_sitez)

            g_imp_jira = row[2]
            print("g_imp_jira = " + g_imp_jira)
            
            g_order_jira = row[3]
            print("g_order_jira[2] = " + g_order_jira)            
            
            g_cir_sz = row[10]
            print("g_cir_sz[10] = " + g_cir_sz)            

            g_ccd = row[5]
            print("g_ccd[5] = " + g_ccd)
                        
            g_telco = row[12]
            print("g_telco[12] = " + g_telco)
            
            #***********  Circuit ID ************
            g_cirid = row[11]            
            g_cirid = str(g_cirid)
            g_cirid = g_cirid.replace("\n","")  
            print("g_cirid[11] = " + g_cirid)          

            g_last_contacted = row[14]
            print("g_last_contacted[14] = " + g_last_contacted)

            #**********  Status ************
            g_status = row[15]
            g_status = str(g_status)
            g_status = g_status.replace("\r","")
            print("g_status[15] = " + g_status)
            
            #*********** Internal Status ***
            g_internal = row[16]
            g_internal = str(g_internal)
            g_internal = g_internal.replace("\n","")
            print("g_internal[16] = " + g_internal)
            
            if (17 in row):
                g_start_date = row[17]
            else:
                g_start_date = ''
            print("g_start_date[17] = " + g_start_date)

#            if (18 in row):
            g_order_date = row[18] 
 #           else:
 #               g_order_date = ''
            print("g_order_date[18] = " + g_order_date)  

        
            #g_deliv_date = row[19]

        
            if (19 in row):
                g_deliv_date = row[19]
            else:
                g_deliv_date = ''                
            print("g_deliv_date[19] = " + g_deliv_date)
            
            if (22 in row):
                g_cpe_date = row[22]
            else:
                g_cpe_date = ''                
            print("g_cpe_date[22] = " + g_cpe_date)

            if (24 in row):
                g_ops_ready = row[24]
            else:
                g_ops_ready = ''                              
            print("g_ops_ready[24] = " + g_ops_ready)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you print out, or use a debugger to introspect, your `row` variable right before the error, does it actually contain 21 items like you're saying it should? I suspect it doesn't.

Comment: f you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Most of your example is not relevant to your problem. You shouuld reduce your code and  data to a [mre] prior to posting. Sometime this will highlight the problem for you.  We certainly don't have access to `'token.pickle'` how would you expect we test your code?

Comment: When you [handled the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspected/printed relevant data in the except suite - is it what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!  Thank you for suggesting the Python debugger tool.  That was very helpful.  The solution is that I needed to change the array "value" to a string when I assign to the variables.  For example, **g_deliv_date = str(row[19])** does the trick.  I can now access all data within the array.

Thank you for your suggestions!